# Batch file - Save multi-line output of FOR command into separate variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I'm running Windows 10 on a Virtual Box virtual machine. My host computer is an ASUS F515J running Windows 11.

I'm writing a batch file, and I want each line of the output of the `net user` command to be saved into a separate variable. Basically, in the following screenshot, I want each line that I've put a red rectangle around to be saved as a separate variable, such as `%userline1%`, `%userline2%`, etc.:
[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8j5m.png)

(I am aware that in batch files, I need to write `%%` instead of `%`)

The for command is really confusing to me, I have never used it before, so when you're writing a command, please make it as clear as possible what part of your code I need to replace with my own variables, with `net user`, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and try to explain what the actual end purpose is? I'm not sure that I see much of a purpose in saving each line of the output to a separate variable, because I would envisage that you would need to perform further parsing and exclusion of those to isolate the domain name and each individual account name. _(You do not really need a variable e.g. `%userline2%`/`%userlist2%` to contain a series of `-` characters for something really!)_

Comment: The purpose is to have a batch file that deactivates all user accounts except the one that's currently active. Once I have each line saved as a variable, I would do something like this to extract the usernames:
`
set account1=%userline3:~0,25%
set account2=%userline3:~25,25%
`
etc. The extra spaces behind the username until 25 characters are reached are not a problem, the net command still works fine when I do the following to deactivate all other accounts:
`
net user %account1% /active:no
net user %account2% /active:no
`
etc. And then I'd do this:
net user %username% /active:yes

Comment: IMO you are going about it all wrong then, especially when some of those accounts listed are probably already disabled/deactivated. The net.exe utility is certainly not something I would be using for the task.

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment about the true purpose of your script, I would probably do this as a one liner using WMIC.exe.

This should work directly from an elevated [command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt), or [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) i.e. 'Run as administrator':

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe UserAccount Where "Disabled='FALSE' And Name!='%UserName%'" Set Disabled=TRUE
```

Please note that your change will unlikely take effect until the next reboot.

*Please also be aware, that if you are running multiple hosts, i.e. different Domain Names, you may wish to exclude more than one specific user `Name` and potentially one or more `Domain`'s. (The example above excludes only the current user's account name from any reported domain).*

Answer (score 0):

This command store each line to separate variable

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "counter=0"
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('net user') do (
    set "var[!counter!]=%%G"
    set /a counter+=1
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Instead of a random number being added to the name of the variable, I need the first line to be saved to %userlist1%, the second line to %userlist2%, etc. How do I do that?